# nest js connect to elastic in docker compose with xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, nest

I'm stucked with connecting to elasticsearch from my nest js app running in docker. I'm getting this error message

```
ResponseError: security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/companies]
```

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: benchy-db
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=benchy
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=0000
    networks:
      - elastic

  server:
    container_name: benchy-api
    build:
      context: ./
    restart: on-failure
    command: bash -c "npm run db:run && npm run rebuild"
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kibana
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
    networks:
      - elastic

  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: esnode1\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - esnode1\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://esnode1:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://esnode1:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "Good to go!";
      '
    networks:
      - elastic

  esnode1:
    depends_on:
      - setup
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esnode1-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=esnode1
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/esnode1/esnode1.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/esnode1/esnode1.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/esnode1/esnode1.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/esnode1/esnode1.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      - esnode1
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibana-data:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://esnode1:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    networks:
      - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    name: elastic
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
  certs:
  esnode1-data:
    driver: local
  kibana-data:
    driver: local
```

this is my .env

```
#ELASTIC VARIABLES
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=DKS481!~=KS!KDJ
KIBANA_PASSWORD=DKS481!~=KS!KDJ
ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
STACK_VERSION=8.2.2
CLUSTER_NAME=docker-cluster
LICENSE=basic
ES_PORT=9200
# ES_PORT=127.0.0.1:9200
KIBANA_PORT=5601
MEM_LIMIT=1073741824
```

and this is my connection from nest js app

```
const elasticClient = new Client({
  node: 'https://esnode1:9200',
  auth: {
    username: process.env.ELASTIC_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.ELASTIC_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    ca: readFileSync('./certs/ca/ca.crt'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

this is certs folder generated by elastic and I'm using this cert
[image]

elastic with kibana working correctly and I can login in kibana, but from my nest js app I'm not able to do this. in my environment elasticsearch will be used just in my VM, when kibana should be accessible from outside. in terms of it I'm thinking weather I need to use xpack security for elastic at all. maybe I can secure just kibana.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Appologies! the issue fixed - I didn't import env in file where I'm initing elasticClient, so the message was complitely clear - "credentials missing", when I've been thinking there was something wrong with certs or whatever.